# Using Robolectric for testing an Android app, which relies on a library project

Tags: android, robolectric

I have an Android app, which relies on a libray project.

I have written some unit tests using Robolectric(v 3.0) for my app.

However when I run my tests, the tests won't complete.
I have tried running from **AndroidStudio(v 1.3)**, in which case the "in progress" animation is shown next to the test, but the test does not complete.

When I run from command line, it gets stuck at about 78%.

> :samples:compileDebugUnitTestJava UP-TO-DATE
>   :samples:compileDebugUnitTestSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :samples:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE :samples:assembleDebugUnitTest
>   UP-TO-DATE
>
> > Building 78% > :samples:testDebug

My DemoActivityTest file:

```
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class,manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml",  sdk = 21, libraries ="../library")
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)

public class DemoActivityTest {
    private DemoActivity activity = null;

@Before
public void setup()  {
    this.activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(DemoActivity.class).create().get();
}

@Test
public void testActivityNotNull() throws Exception {
    assertNotNull(activity);
}
```

}

The problem happens only when I access the library classes from my DemoActivity.java
The test runs fine if I remove "library" related code.

This link(http://robolectric.org/using-libraries/) says:
Using Libraries with Gradle

If you use Gradle to build your application and you are using RobolectricGradleTestRunner to run your tests, no additional configuration is required. This is because the Android Gradle plugin will merge 3rd party library resources with your application's resources at build time.

Request you to help me ressolve this error.

Thanks

Comment: First remove the manifest file specification for runner. Can you share more details what is library related code is doing during activity onCreate?

Comment: What does it mean exactly when you say "it get's stuck at 78%"? It just stays like this forever, or does it give you an error message? Also: Have you tried without specifying library in the @Config annotation? We use Robolectric with libraries that depend on other libraries without this problem. So it definitely should work. But we have little to work with here.

Comment: @Eugen: I have tried removing manifest file specification for runner, that does not help either.The library is for displaying Circular menu.During activity onCreate() basic setup related to displaying the circular menu is done.(Please see onCreate() in : https://github.com/oguzbilgener/CircularFloatingActionMenu/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/com/oguzdev/circularfloatingactionmenu/samples/MenuWithFABActivity.java for details). i created instance of MenuWithFABActivity class using 
Robolectric.buildActivity(MenuWithFABActivity.class).create().get(),I see the behavior mentioned in my post

Comment: @haffax : It does not throw any error, it stays at that level even if you keep running the test for hours.
I have tried removing "library" from at Config, without success.


I tried creating a simple class(class which has a method to return string resource) inside a library, the test runs fine.
Looks like if I am doing UI related stuff in the library, I have a problem.

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea then. What you can try is to debug this: From Android Studio run tests in debug mode and break execution once you see the endless spinner and look where test execution thread is stuck at. Maybe this can give you an idea of what is wrong.

Comment: @ramyanayak when the test runs endless then take a thread dump to see where the tests gets stuck. Within AndroidStudio you can do this by the camera symbol left to your unit tests method list. Maybe this could be a known issue see https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1889 and referenced issues.